# How do I render a template driven form invalid if a custom field validator fails, in this Angular 15 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been working an app with Angular 15. I use a hand-coded JSON and **[JSON server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)** to perform CRUD operations on a "employees" JSON.

I am currently working on adding a custom validation ro a `<select>` element.

In `employee-form.component.html` I have:

```
<form class="modal-content" #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addEmployee(employeeForm)">
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header py-2">
      <h4 class="modal-title">New employee</h4>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body py-2">
      <div *ngIf="isSuccess" class="text-center alert alert-success">
        Employee added successfully!
      </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-1">
          <label class="form-label" for="firstName">First name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstName" placeholder="First name" [(ngModel)]="firstname" #first_name="ngModel" required/>
          <div *ngIf="first_name.touched && first_name.errors?.['required']"  class="invalid-feedback">First name is required.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-1">
          <label class="form-label" for="lastName">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name" [(ngModel)]="lastname" #last_name="ngModel" required />
          <div *ngIf="last_name.touched && last_name.errors?.['required']"  class="invalid-feedback">Last name is required.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-1">
        <label class="form-label d-block" for="avatar">Photo</label>
        <input type="file" class="file-upload-btn" name="avatar" id="avatar" [(ngModel)]="avatar" (change)="pickAvatar($event)">
      </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-1">
          <label class="form-label" for="job">Job</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job" id="job" placeholder="Job" [(ngModel)]="job" #job_title="ngModel" required  />
          <div *ngIf="job_title.touched && job_title.errors?.['required']" class="invalid-feedback">Job is required.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-1">
        <label class="form-label" for="job">Skills</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="skills" id="skills" placeholder="Skills separated by comma" [(ngModel)]="skills"/>
    </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-1">
        <label class="form-label" for="department">Department</label>
        <select class="form-select" name="department" id="department" [(ngModel)]="deptno" #emp_department="ngModel" required>
          <option value="-1">Pick a department</option>
          <option *ngFor="let department of departments" [value]="department.value">
            {{department.label}}
          </option>
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="emp_department.touched && emp_department.value == -1" class="invalid-feedback">You must pick a department</div>
      </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-0">
          <label class="form-label d-block">Gender</label>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" id="male" value="male" [(ngModel)]="gender" />
              <label class="form-label" for="male">male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" id="femele" value="femele" [(ngModel)]="gender" />
              <label class="form-label" for="femele">femele</label>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="position-relative mb-1">
          <label class="form-label" for="bio">Bio</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="bio" id="bio" type="text" placeholder="Bio" [(ngModel)]="bio"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer py-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!employeeForm.valid">Add employee</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In `employee-form.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../../models/empModel';
import { NgForm, FormGroup, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../services/employee.service';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from '../employee-list/employee-list.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-form',
  templateUrl: './employee-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-form.component.scss']
})

export class EmployeeFormComponent {

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService, private employeeListComponent: EmployeeListComponent) {
    this.deptno = -1;
    this.gender = 'male';
  }

  public empsArray: Employee[] = [];
  public departments: any[] = [
    {value: 10, label: 'Management'},
    {value: 20, label: 'Sales'},
    {value: 30, label: 'Software'},
    {value: 40, label: 'Finance'}
  ];
  public newEmployee: any = {}
  public empno: number = 0;
  public deptno: number = 0;
  public firstname: string = '';
  public lastname: string = '';
  public gender: string = '';
  public avatar: string = '';
  public job: string = '';
  public bio: string = '';
  public skills: string = '';
  public isSuccess: boolean = false;

  public pickAvatar(event: any) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    this.avatar = file.name;
  }

  public setAvatar() {
    this.newEmployee.avatar = this.avatar.length ? this.avatar : `${this.gender}.png`;
  }

  public validateDepartment(form: NgForm) {
   if (this.deptno == -1) {
    form.invalid;
   } 
  }

  public doSkillsArray() {
    this.newEmployee.skills = this.skills.split(',');
  }

  public addEmployee(form: NgForm) {

    this.newEmployee = {
      empno: this.empno,
      deptno: this.deptno,
      firstname: this.firstname,
      lastname: this.lastname,
      gender: this.gender,
      avatar: this.avatar,
      job: this.job,
      bio: this.bio,
      skills: this.skills
    };

    this.setAvatar();

    this.doSkillsArray();

    this.validateDepartment(form);

    this.employeeService.addEmployee(this.newEmployee).subscribe(
      (_response: Employee) => {
        // Show success alert
        this.isSuccess = true;

        // Render the employee list after adding a new employee
        this.employeeListComponent.getEmployees();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

#### The goal

In the form above, a "You must pick a department" message is displayed  over the `<select>` element *if no department is selected*.

I also need to render *the form* invalid untill and unless a department is selected.

For this purpose, I have:

```
public validateDepartment(form: NgForm) {
   if (this.deptno == -1) {
    form.invalid;
   } 
}
```

It fails. I also tried this (which also fails):

```
public validateDepartment(form: NgForm) {
   if (this.deptno != -1) {
    form.valid;
   } 
}
```

A **Stackblitz** can be seen **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c5sudc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Femployee-form%2Femployee-form.component.ts)**.

#### Questions

1. Why is the form valid while the  element is not?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: For this kind of work, you should consider use reactive form. You will have way more control on the behavior of your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "required" in a select should be over an option with [ngValue]="null" or [ngValue]="undefined"

```
<select
  class="form-select"
  name="department"
  id="department"
  [(ngModel)]="deptno"
  #emp_department="ngModel"
  required
>
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected hidden>Pick a department</option>
  <option *ngFor="let department of departments" [ngValue]="department.value">
    {{department.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

NOTE: When a input inside the form is invalid the form is also invalid

**Update**
To create a custom validator in Template driven forms, you need use a directive that implements Validator, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms).

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[isNot]',
  standalone:true,
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NotValueValidatorDirective , multi: true}]
})
export class NotValueValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('isNot') value:any = null;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (control.value==this.value)
        return this.value?{error:"can be "+this.value}:{error:"can be null"}
    return null
  }
}
```

And use, e.g.

```
<select isNot="-1">
   <option value="-1" hidden>Choose one</option>
   ...
</select>
```

**Update2**
the app.module becomes like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import {NotValueValidatorDirective} from './components/employee-form/ifnot.directive'

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule],
  declarations: [
    FilterPipe,
    ...
    NotValueValidatorDirective //<--add the directive to the module
  ]
```

The employee-form.component

```
<div class="position-relative mb-1">
            <label class="form-label" for="department">Department</label>
            <select class="form-select" name="department" id="department" [(ngModel)]="deptno" #emp_department="ngModel" isNot="0">
              <!---I Change your pick a department to value=0-->
              <!--we can use hidden to not show when the select is open-->
              <option value="0" hidden>Pick a department</option>
              <option *ngFor="let department of departments" [value]="department.value">
                {{department.label}}
              </option>
            </select>
            <!--we use .invalid-->
            <div *ngIf="emp_department.touched && emp_department.invalid class="invalid-feedback">You must pick a department</div>
          </div>
```

The directive is the same removing "standalone:true"

Comment: I have added an illustration of the issue to the question.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, the property "invalid" of a ngForm is read-only, you can not use some like `this.form.invalid=true`. To create a custom validator in Template driven forms, you need use a directive than implements Validator, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms). Really is a simple directive with a function validate, the example use "input" because want to check if a name is not Bob.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, I put your code in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zibsx9?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter) with the directive isNot="0"

Comment: What is `isNot`?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, it's a directive (in the stackblitz it's in the same main.ts). Don't forget include in your declarations in your module if you're using modules or in imports if you're using standalone components.

Comment: I have added it to imports: `[imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule, DeptValidationDirective]`. It does mot work.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, you're not working with standalone components, you need add in the "declarations" of the module the directive, not in imports. When we use modules, in imports only should be the "modules". Sorry my english

Comment: There is a **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c5sudc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Femployee-form%2Femployee-form.component.ts)** with the current state of the project.

Comment: I update again the answer, and fork your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cere16?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Femployee-form%2Femployee-form.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Femployee-form%2Fifnot.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Default gender can be selected as below:

-- just say "checked" in html:-

```
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" id="male" checked value="male" />
```

or it can be given through component as well like:-

```
<label *ngFor="let radiobutton of radioItems">
  <input type="radio" name="options" (click)="model.option = radiobutton"
  [checked]="radiobutton === model.option">{{radiobutton}}
</label>
```

and in component-ts file:-

```
export class AppComponent  {
  radioItems: Array<string>;
  model   = {option: 'Male'};

  constructor() {
    this.radioItems = ['Gender', 'Male', 'Female'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about the `<select>` element.

Comment: This answers alternative question that was asked initially.